# Adding styling to TypeScript, React NPM package

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, npm

I have a TypeScript(TS), React project which I'm using to hold all my React components.
I'm creating an NPM package out of this project which I'm then consuming in separate React projects. I'm running into a problem where I don't know how to export the styling along with the TS components.

Using components from the NPM package result in errors:
`Module not found: Can't resolve '../css/footer.css'`

When I create my directory for packaging(dist) all my components are there but none of the CSS. I'm running `tsc` to create this directory. All my components and CSS lie within the same src folder.

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Do I need to move my styling out of css files and into ts files that make use of the `<style jsx>` tag or is there another 'better' way of achieving the desired result.
The desired result being an NPM package that contains all styling and components rolled into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tsc` is the command for compiling TypeScript files to Javascript. CSS files are not Typescript files which is why they aren't included in the compilation.

If you want to import CSS (or any other asset types) and output it alongside your other compiled files then you'll probably want to use a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). There are even tools like [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) which provide sensible bundler configuration so that you can focus on writing your library.

Alternatively, you could write your styles in TypeScript too, with a library like [styled-jsx](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx).

Even if you're not interested in using one, it's worth taking a look at the various templates for TypeScript + React npm packages to see how they work.

- https://github.com/pankod/react-typescript-npm-package-boilerplate
- https://github.com/dstpierre/react-npm-typescript-boilerplate

Comment: As the package React project also contains images would you advise making use of Webpack over your second suggestion?

Comment: Yeah! For sure. Lots of library authors find that Rollup works a bit better for bundling libraries, but go with whatever you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Rollup works good and best for component libraries. https://github.com/Sivakumar00/react-typescript-npm-boilerplate created this boilerplate for react-typescript with rollup, storybook